# How to delete all messages from a rabbit MQ in java

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

We have a job which will run at only End of day.
During EOD it will read all the messages from RabbitMQ and generate a file.
After a successful file generation we need to delete all the messages in RabbitMQ.
Is there a way to do it from Java code?

We are using `channel.basicGet(QueueName,false);`

If I pass `autoAck` as true instead of false then it will delete the messages but if there is any exception while processing then message will be lost.

To overcome this I used `channel.queuepurge(QueueName);`
but it is not working.

So our requirement is we need to read the messages from queue generate a file after successful file generation then we need to delete all messages else If any failures during processing then we should not delete the messages from queue

Comment: Great if you can show us some code....

Answer (score 1):

Use RabbitAdmin to purge the queue . Note the difference between purging and deleting .

```
Delete - Delete the queue
Purge - Empty the message of the queue.
```

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-amqp-dist/1.3.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitAdmin.html#purgeQueue%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29

```
@Autowired private RabbitAdmin admin;

...

admin.purgeQueue("queueName", false);
```